# What to call the natural transformation in the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, terminology, functors, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

The Yoneda lemma is an isomorphism between `f a` and `(a <-) ~> f` where the Yoneda embedding is `Y = (<-)`. Is there a descriptive name for one particular side of the isomorphism, namely the natural transformation from the Yoneda embedding: `Y a ~> f`? An alternative to:

> hom-set of presheaf homomorphism from the representable presheaf `Y a` to `f`

I ask because the Haskell datatype [`Co.Yoneda f a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.5/docs/Data-Functor-Yoneda.html) defines the natural transformation of the covariant Yoneda lemma and it would be useful to have a description that explains its role in the Yoneda lemma.

```
type    Yoneda :: (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype Yoneda f a = Yoneda ((a ->) ~> f)
```

Comment: Yoneda isomorphism. Catchy names create an unnecessary barrier of entry.

Comment: I want to describe the natural transformation part of the Yoneda isomorphism specifically, if a clearer description than that exists. I didn't use catchy in any frivolous way.